# Connect to mysql datasource with a way other than odbc

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports, odbc

I have been using odbc to connect to my mysql database in order to view Crystal Reports but I'm afraid of security breaches since I have to connect remotely and I have to change the ip address in my cpanel everytime my ip changes, So, is there any other way I can connect pro-grammatically to my database other than odbc?

P.S my application is created using c#

thanks

Comment: If youre IP is changing why not use DynDNS to keep a track of your IP address, when it changes then your record held with them changes.  then you can just put in a named instance rather than using the IP Address. But can you show us your code to show how your connecting to see if there is anyway that it can be tweaked to help prevent from any vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into DynDNS but it's a paid service and besides that I will install my application in around 10 PC's so it will be hard for me to do it for all the PCs, I'm not using any code for Crystal reports all that I'm doing is using odbc and creating a new datasource using mysql driver

Comment: is it private or public server where the reports \ connection is being made?

Comment: it is a private server @SimonPrice

Comment: rather than using IP address, could you not use a named instance to connect to your server? that way if the IP changes you dont have to change all the records for it

Comment: and how can I do that? If you have any helpful link then I would appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88832/discussion-between-simon-price-and-wanna-be-android-developer).